# Does PHImageManager return images in pixel or point size for 2x and 3x screens?

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

I'm loading images from the camera roll via PHImageManager, but the returned images are not retina resolution. Do I have to provide a multiplier myself for 2x and 3x or do I have something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
class ReviewableImageView: UIImageView {

    ...unrelated code

    imageRequestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    imageRequestOptions.deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat
    imageRequestOptions.resizeMode = .Exact

    ...unrelated code

    self.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true

    ... unrelated code

    func reloadImage(){
        let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()//PHImageManager()

        imageManager.requestImageForAsset(self.imageAsset,
            targetSize: self.frame.size,
            contentMode: .AspectFit,
            options: imageRequestOptions,
            resultHandler: { (image: UIImage!, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) in
                self.image = image
        })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

According to my experiments with `PHImageManager`you must provide a `targetSize` in **pixels**. For example, imagine you wanna request an image with the size 400x800 px. For this case you can set the target size like the following:

```
 // Set target size.
 let targetSize = CGSizeMake(400, 800)
```

Regarding your code example, in the [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame) stated that:

> The coordinates of the frame rectangle are always specified in points.

So to set the correct target size in this case you can use code similar to the following:

```
// Get scale factor associated with the screen. 
let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

// Request the image.
imageManager.requestImageForAsset(self.imageAsset,
            targetSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width * scale, self.frame.size.height * scale),
            contentMode: .AspectFit,
            options: imageRequestOptions,
            resultHandler: { (image, info) -> Void in
                // Handle the result here...
        })
```

Comment: I've also tested and found that requestImageForAsset returns an image with a scale of 1.0, so you'd want to specify pixels for targetSize.

Comment: I would use `nativeScale` which will return exactly amount of pixels that's visible. `scale` is higher for some iPhone models. [Screen Geometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/Displays/Displays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH108-SW2)

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell from your code whether you realize that the `resultHandler` will be called *multiple times*. The *first* time it is called, you may get a low-resolution low-quality image. But *eventually* it will be called with a correctly scaled image.

Comment: Actually, I think because he's using `deliveryMode = .HighQualityFormat` he will only get the high quality image, and the `resultHandler` will only fire once per image. [From doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageRequestOptions_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryMode)